# Create specific item with one empty div (<div />) and css only

Tags: html, css

For example if i want to create this:

[image: caffeine holder]

What should I do?

I know how to bind div tag with css but my problem is I think I dont know css as much as i should to do this

Comment: If you don't know CSS as much as you should, maybe you should research some CSS instead? StackOverflow is for help with your existing code, and not "how do I do this?"-quoestions.

Comment: You can make shapes using CSS, but given the fact that you don't seem to know anything about CSS yet, I certainly wouldn't start with that, because it's very complicated, and often images are better. I'd follow any [beginners tutorial](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/) to get some idea on how to use `classes` and other ways to apply styles to elements ("bind with CSS" as you call it). At first you can try to just give the div some size and color, and then quickly move on to background images, which I think it the best way forward for this.

Comment: learn to walk before you try to run

Comment: @Pete lol but you soo right

Answer (score 3):

```css
.abc {
  width: 100px;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.abc::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: -20px;
}

.abc::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 23px;
  height: 35px;
  top: 0;
  right: -30px;
  border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
  border: 13px solid black;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">

</div>
```

Comment: Yeah i realised it now @TemaniAfif . Will try to fix it. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example with **one** div and **without pseudo element** *(with some animation also)*

```css
.coffee {
  width:300px;
  height:170px;
  margin-top:10px;
  border-radius:0 0 30px 30px;
  background:
  radial-gradient(circle at left,#fff 52%,transparent 53%) 225px 20px/50px 60px,
  radial-gradient(circle at left,#000 52%,transparent 53%) 225px 0px/80px 100px,
  radial-gradient(circle at top left,#000 70%,transparent 71%) 205px 120px/20px 20px,
  radial-gradient(circle at top right,#000 70%,transparent 71%) 75px 120px/20px 20px,
  linear-gradient(#000,#000) center 120px /calc(50% - 40px) 20px,
  linear-gradient(#000,#000) top center/50% 120px,
  linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom/100% 30px;
  
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:0.3s all linear;
}
.coffee:hover {
  height:180px;
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="coffee"></div>
```